# Проблема с QRegExp

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

Собственно есть такой паттерн:

```
QRegExp rx = QRegExp("^(?!ТЕСТ-М[^\\S*\\d*]).*$");
qDebug() << rx.indexIn("привет") << rx.indexIn("ТЕСТ-М60") << rx.indexIn("ТЕСТ-М");
```

На выходе получаю `0 0 0`, соответственно все три слова сматчились. Однако, этот паттерн не должен был сматчить третье слово. И, например, здесь этого не происходит:
[regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F!%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A2-%D0%9C%5B%5E%5CS*%5Cd*%5D%29.*%24&i=%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A2-%D0%9C%0D%0A%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A2-%D0%9C60%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%0D%0A&o=m)

Может я как-то не так задаю паттерн в Qt?

Comment: Может, вам нужен `QRegExp("^(?!ТЕСТ-М(?:\\s|$)).*$")`? Строка не должна начинаться с `ТЕСТ-М`, за которым следует пробельный символ или конец строки?

Comment: _`[^\\S*\\d*]`_ - вот это - фигня.

Answer (score 0):

Именно про QRegExp не знаю и не могу сейчас проверить, но для других компонентов Qt, а конкретно QMap сталкивался с тем что в случае запроса по ключу которого не было возвращалось значение по умолчанию да еще и в саму структуру вставлялось, приходилось обращение оборачивать в `if (map.contains("id")) { value = map["id"].toString()}` . Возможно, тут такое же поведение и сначала надо убедиться что паттерн вообще присутствует в строке при помощи exactMatch и только потом уже искать его в строке